# how to send an object from RESTful client to WCF RESTful server using C#

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, .net-4.0

I am trying to send data from my RESTful client to my RESTful server. How do I pass an object which contains string, int, byte[], etc. using c# web/desktop client. I need help for client side implementation. Please guide me.

**My server code like:**

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "")]
 void GetObject(Object obj);
```

Comment: Such operation will not work. WCF cannot use Object - it must use concrete type to be able to deserialize passed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use KnownTypeAttribute to specify what types that obj may be, so that the WCF DataContractSerializer can work.